# What is the probability getting 2 jokers in 3 draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My friend and I are playing Dicey Dungeons (great game btw) and we are trying to reverse engineer combinatorics / permutations in our head.

The translation of our problem amounts to the title: What is the probability of getting 2 jokers in 3 draws? There are 54 cards, and 2 of them are jokers.

In our Dicey Dungeons problem, our problem is this: We have a deck of 14 cards, where there is one card that is duplicated. We want to know the probability we will get two of the same card in the first draw of 3 cards.

In the long run, there are multiple cards with duplicates, so in our deck of 14, we might have something like `AAABBBCCDEFGHH`, but for now we assume we have `ABCDEFGHIJKLMM`, and we want to know the probability of getting M in 3 draws. How do we calculate this?

Comment: This follows a [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and has probability $\dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{52}{1}}{\binom{54}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{477}$.  The hypergeometric distribution should be easily applicable to your other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, you have $54$ cards, two of which are jokers.

On the first draw, either you draw a joker (probability: $2/54$) or you do not (probability: $52/54$).

If your first draw is a joker, you now need to know the probability of drawing one joker from the remaining $53$ cards.  Drawing it on the first try happens with probability $1/53$ and you do not care what the next card is, so you draw it with probability $52/52$.  If you draw it on the second try, you draw any *other* card first, with probability $52/53$ and then draw the remaining joker, with probability $1/52$.

Alternatively, your first draw is not a joker, with probability $52/54$, and your next two draws are jokers, with probabilities $2/53$ and $1/52$, respectively.

Collecting these paths through drawing two jokers in three draws, we have

- JJx: $(2/54)(1/53)(52/52)$
- JxJ: $(2/54)(52/53)(1/52)$
- xJJ: $(52/54)(2/53)(1/52)$

In all three cases, the numerators we multiple together are $1$, $2$, and $52$ and the denominators we multiply together are $54$, $53$, and $52$.  So the total probability of two jokers in three draws is

$$  3 \cdot \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 52}{52 \cdot 53 \cdot 54} = \frac{1}{53 \cdot 9} = \frac{1}{477}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: is there a generalized formula for your final conclusion of joining the numerators and denominators? Can i also get the answer in like a n choose k form?

Comment: This calculation is equivalent to 3 choose 2 (for the number of ways the two jokers can land in the three drawn cards) times 54 choose 3 (for the number of different three card subsets of 54 cards).

Comment: I see, thank you. These types of problems are so crazy to wrap my brain around but thinking of it as a hypergeometric distribution helped, especially when considering multivariate cases.